# Running fork inside a loop produces unexpected results (measuring process switch time)

Tags: c, operating-system

I am writing a program to measure the time it takes to perform a process switch. In order to do this I am having a parent write one byte messages to its child and the child read it.

My problem is in this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<2; i++)
{
    if(fork()==0) //child process, read
    {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        read(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
    }

    else //parent process
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(pipefd[1]);
        close(pipefd[0]);
    }
}
```

In order to test to see how often the fork was hitting the parent and child I put a printf statement in, and I got around 15 statements printed to the screen. How this is possible considering the loop should only run twice?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because each child process is going to create other processes.

After the `if` block is executed, each child will return at the beginning of the loop and `fork()` again, until `i == 2` in all child processes.

#### Edit :

In order to avoid that, I suggest to use something like this :

```
if(fork() == 0)
{
    //Do stuff
    break;
}
```

Maybe this is not the most elegant way, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas on how I would only communicate between a parent and a child then? The idea is I would implement a clock and time the time it takes to send/receive the one byte message (because that would force a process switch,) but I'm not sure how to do that, as it seems I should only call fork() once then.

Comment: Still doesn't explain 15 outputs... you'd only get 4 processes, which should give 4 outputs.

Comment: @user120920 Please see my edit and tell me if it worked.

Comment: @thang I agree with you, but I think that the problem is still the same.